# Adding Windows system sound

Tags: wpf, windows, installation

Playing a system sounds is simple. However, when looking at the ControlPanel->Sounds->Sounds, I see some programs like Itunes and TortoiseSVN have added custom sounds. How to achieve that? I was not able to find anything.

Thanks,

/Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom sounds are defined in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents`. You will find EventLabels and Schemes there linked together and referencing media flies for certain events. AFAIK there it no API to manage those, so you have to work with registry directly if you want to add your own sounds.

Playing custom events will still be simple, as you already noticed.